# nvcc takes ages to compile simple code

Tags: cuda

I have this very simple code and nvcc is taking ages to compile (it loads two of my CPU cores 100% and never stops). Is this due to some loop unrolling? Is there a simpler way as to initialize local memory faster?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuComplex.h"
__global__ void test()
 {
 cuComplex myPoints[20][20];

 for (int i=0; i<20;i++)
     for (int j=0; j<20;j++)
    {
       myPoints[i][j].x=0.0;
        myPoints[i][j].y=0.0;
    }
 for (int i=0; i<20;i++)
     for (int j=0; j<20;j++)
   {

        printf("%d %d",myPoints[i][j].x,myPoints[i][j].y);
   }


 }

 main()
 {
 }
```

Comment: which cuda version?  It compiles pretty quick for me on cuda 4.1

Comment: it is Cuda 5.. Just the latest release.. I'll try to compile with cuda 4.2

Comment: Infact on cuda 4.2.1 it is very fast as you say.. so what's the problem .. a bug or a new feature in cuda 5?

Comment: I see the long compile time in CUDA 5 as well. I don't really have an answer for you, but I observe that 20*20*sizeof(cuComplex) is a lot of register space to be sucking up per thread. If I place __ shared__ in front of it, the compile time drops to something short again. Just sharing an observation. If you intend to write code that runs on a single thread, it's not typically a very interesting thing to do on a GPU. If you do intend to allocate that much register/local memory per thread, you'll run out of it pretty quick for any reasonable number of threads

Comment: That myPoints array would not be "register space", it would be local memory. It may not make sense for it to be shared between threads, and there probably isn't enough shared memory for each thread to have that much space. It's not uncommon for programs to use significant local memory per thread, and in some cases, it's not even a bottleneck.  This sounds like a compiler bug.

Comment: Since the trip counts for all loops are known at compile time, the compiler may try to completely unroll the loops, at which point the local memory object myPoints could theoretically be allocated in registers. Not that this would be very practical, and the compiler probably has a size check heuristic to prevent that. Regardless of what happens under the hood inside the compiler, cases of excessive compile times should be treated as bugs. I would therefore suggest to user1750561 to file a bug via https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: Yes I used "register" and "local memory" interchangeably, I should not have.  Nevertheless it may be useful to draw attention to the line that if modified, may offer clues as to a possible temporary workaround.

Comment: @RobertCrovella filed a bug already, since the repro was trivial. Thanks Robert!

Comment: Thanks to everyone... What I am trying to do is to have a block update as much as (32x20)x(32x20) points  and then save results atomically to a global. Each thread is assigned 20x20 points to take care of. Shared memory is too small....

Answer (score 1):

This apparent compiler bug has been reported to the NVIDIA compiler team